Where to find/learn standard meaning of ω or φ, etc., in RF circuit design
I am retired from a long career in Electronic Warfare (EW) in the US Navy, followed by decades in communications in two-way radio engineering, cellular system technical management, etc, and then a later career in IT in system administration followed by decades in software development.
In my Navy career, though I have no formal mathematics training beyond high-school geometry, they did teach enough trigonometry and basic calculus in my EW training that, at that time, I at least was able to perform well enough in that role. But that limited training, 50 years ago, is the extent of my mathematics training. After that, and after doing electronic design, including limited RF design, I pretty much forgot everything I knew about RF design and the limited mathematics I understood so long ago.
Now I am retired and I want to go back into electronics and RF design for my own gratification. I'm a 55-year licensed amateur radio (ham radio) operator and now that I am retired I want to get more involved in the technical side of the hobby - things I once did very well but long forgot. I want to design and build a frequency-synthesizer-based SDR, with digital filtering demod, etc.
The point of the history is that I've some reasonable background for this decades ago but I'm too old now to start college - and my health is too unreliable to do that anyway, so I am stuck with self-teaching online and the history answers the guidelines for telling what I know and don't know.
So to my question; when I see formulas for designing RF circuits, there are all kinds of Greek symbols that I don't know, for instance, jω. I know the j operator but not the ω. I have searched for days and I find some definitions where it is defined as frequency, others where it is defined as 2πfC, or 2πfL, or as bandwidth, or other things that tell me there may not be a single standard definition - and yet, virtually all of the RF design books I am reading, currently Crawford's Frequency Synthesizer Design Handbook, offer no definition or explanation for ω or φ or many other Greek symbols. I also don't find definitions for those in any of my college-level math books from College Algebra through Stewart's Calculus. In the RF Design books, the symbols show up in complex formulas from the very first pages but with the assumption that I already know what it means in context, or in any context for that matter.
So my question is, then, where are such things taught and where will I find them, and all the common things like them? What books, in RF design or in Mathematics, did I miss or am I missing? And I don't necessarily mean which title by which author, but what class or topic am I missing - though specific books might also help but then we get into that whole "opinion" thing and that is not the intention of my question.

ω is usually angular frequency, ω = 2pif where f is frequency in Hz. 2πfC where C is capacitance in F is capacitive reactance. φ is sometimes used to represent phase.  Not sure where you would go to find a good reference though.

That makes sense; so those cases where a definition is given are likely exceptions.  I did just find a pretty good explanation on wikipedia, of all places.  Angular frequency was the key I was missing in that one but, like you said, a good pointer to what class or topic where such things are taught in university programs will help.

Find and buy a used starting electronics book that targets self-learning and doesn't require lectures to supplement it. I can't recommend a specific one, off-hand, but perhaps one of the more important things to look for will me that it covers Cramer's Rule (math) and mesh (KVL) and nodal (KCL) analysis methods, with solved example circuits included.
In addition, you have access to the world of YouTube and the Khan Academy. Make use of them. There are some really good teaching materials being offered. There is also the MIT opencourseware where you can select classes, with lectures and materials, almost as if you were taking classes at a university. Use the web, search for recommendations on any topic where you are motivated. You will probably find a few things that will work well for you. On mathematics itself, I can definitely recommend 3Blue1Brown on YouTube (here, too.) Pretty much anything he does will be visual and intuitive and is well-produced.
Find and buy a used starting good physics book. In this case, I would recommend Matter & Interactions by Chabay and Sherwood. Get the latest edition, if possible. But earlier ones are quite good. It does cover much about electronics, but provides a more solid understanding of the underlying mechanisms, too. You should also access the Feynman Lecture Series. The first volume is pretty much a cake walk. It won't be until volume II that the math starts getting heavy. But you can skip around in volume II to get some glimpse of how we know what we know about electromagnetism forces (and material science related to them.)
You should also get and learn to use some tools to help out. Desmos -- look under the Tools menu -- has a nice online grapher. They also include a 3D graphing tool that may also help at times. You should also consider learning to use GeoGebra and find and learn, especially, how to use vector fields and contour plots. Finally, and this is pretty important in terms of saving time over the long run though, as with everything, it will cost you learning curves in the short run, you should get familiar with some free tools to solve equations for you, symbolically. I'd recommend getting SageMath and adding in SymPy. These will also require you to learn some Python language, but not much. Just the basics.
Just some added tidbits. You should want to get familiar with Euler's and understand that multiplication of complex numbers involves both scaling and rotation, unlike the case with real numbers which only involves scaling and no rotation. This also feeds into why Euler's is important in electronics (signals often dampen out [scale down exponentially] while also oscillating [rotating around the circle with time].)
On the mathematics side, if possible, you want to be familiar with differential equations and how to solve them up through Laplace methods -- as a goal, anyway. Also, it would help to understand linear systems of equations and matrix theory and, eventually, graph theory. As it turns out, any valid circuit is also a directed graph. Directed graph theory captures all of this as KCL is found in the rowspace and right nullspace and Ohm's Law and KVL is found in the columspace and left nullspace. (And here is a description of the four fundamental subspaces, for a short summary in review.)
As you can see, there's a world out there. And you are going to have to use your own personal motivations to decide which thing to take up and run with, one at a time. Set yourself a project goal that bites off a few things, but not too much. You want to stretch yourself, but not to the point of breaking and then losing motivation. You want to see success each step of the way.
And when you run into a specific issue you are struggling with, write here. See if someone can help. Or find someone in your area -- there are meetup groups, for example -- though I also do remember you saying that going to class would be a difficult ask so perhaps meetups would also be tough. That said, we do have telephones and you can build relationships where you can just call someone to help, perhaps. Don't give up on that idea. You may get lucky there. And, perhaps, consider just making a visit to a community college and the electronics department to talk with the department head there. It's one trip. Not lots of trips. And it is possible they can think of a way to help out. Don't forget that there are many local online courses now at community colleges and, old enough, these classes in the US may be free for you. So ask about that, too.
Personal note to you. A few of the very best people I got to know were 20+ year Navy, when I worked at Lockheed in Burbank on P3 systems as a contractor. I learned quickly to respect them in almost every possible way, not only in their professional work but as a human being I wanted to grow more towards, myself. Just FYI. I very much wish you the best!

Thanks.  I knew lots of P3 folks in the 70s.  They did in the air what I did shipboard and on shore stations.  I did find the Physics book answer.  University Physics Volume 1 from OpenStax.  That was the missing part of my reading that, hopefully, will let me go on with the other studies.  Much of what you suggests is over my head but that's the whole purpose, to develop a roadmap to get started on the rest.  Thank you.

@Dale I wanted to quickly sketch out the larger map. It's vast, so you will have to use your own motivations to be selective about where to start and the directions to head in from there. Before Lockheed, I'd never met long-term, well-trained, and experienced Navy personnel. I just imagined them as the rest of us hoi polloi. But working beside 20+ yr Navy personnel on the P3D project I learned it was a privilege and an honor. They helped me see and want to change my worse aspects while pushing also to develop what I consider some of my better qualities today. I respected them like few I knew.

The publications of the ARRL are a handy source of the information that you are looking for at a level you should be able to understand especially since you have a ham license. Start with the ARRL Handbook (you don't need the latest version and used earlier editions are available at reasonble cost).

I have a shelf full of ARRL Handbooks, every few years from when I got my license in 1969.  They're great resources.  They're great for basic theory but don't really get into the math and deep RF design.  The math chapter in the handbook talks about decibels, and that's pretty much it.   Don't get me wrong; I love the handbooks and the ARRL, and appreciate the response; others with similar questions should also take this advice.
